# Express ignores response.send() call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple server. Code is explained below:

```js
const express = require("express");
 
const app = express();
 
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
 
app.get("/about-me", function(_, response) {
    response.render("about_me.hbs");
});
app.get("/", function (_, response) {
    response.render("index.hbs");
});
app.all(/.*/, function (_, response) { // 404 page
    response.sendStatus(404); // set status code to 404
    response.send("<h1>404 Not Found</h1>"); // send a body
}
app.listen(3000);
```

But when I opened http://localhost:3000/not-exist , there was "Not Foun<" text. Why it's happening?

Comment: You would like to see 404 Not Found but are seeing "Not Foun"? Is this correct?

Comment: you can chain the status with the response `response.status(404).send(...)`

Comment: @LazarNikolic, yes, i saw Not Foun<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send two responses to a single request.

Use [`sendStatus`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus) **or** [`send`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send).

If you want to control the status code when you use `send`, use [`status`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status).